# What are the names of the 2 pieces of a quick release strap buckle?

Tags: single-word-requests

This is the product that I am referring to:

https://www.ji-horng.com/show/plastic-buckle-what-is-side-release-buckle.htm

What do you call the head/male/protruding piece. What do you call the tail/female/inverted piece?

Comment: I can't follow your link, but [this site](https://www.ji-horng.com/show/plastic-buckle-what-is-side-release-buckle.htm) just says *Side release buckle essentially consists of two parts, one is **male buckle**, and the other one is **female buckle.***

Comment: I changed my link to the one provided by @FumbleFingers. Is there no other word than male, female?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The main part, the female one often with the release button, is called the **'buckle'**. This is a common word and what people usually will call this thing.

The smaller flat part that sticks in is called the **'tongue'** or **'latch plate'**. These are somewhat technical terms and native speakers will understand them but most likely won't produce these terms easily.

It usually comes out as 'stick it into the buckle' (where 'it' is understood by pragmatics to be the male part). Or simply 'buckle your seatbelt' with no mention of the parts. If a non-technical native speaker needs to refer to the male part, it would most likely come out as 'the flat part' (and the female part very naturally as 'buckle').

The Wikipedia article on [seat belts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seat_belt) mentions this terminology but, as is usual with encyclopedia articles, doesn't use language the way non-technical people do.

Comment: I don't think latch plate is right for a buckle.

Comment: @Lambie I don't think I said that ' latch plate' is right for 'buckle'. And I also don't believe it. 'Latch plate' (and 'tongue') is for the male part, and 'buckle' for the female part. But to repeat what I said, buckle is a natural non-technical term for the female part and 'latch plate is very technical for the male part (ie not something a native speaker would naturally use.

Comment: You misread me: The side release buc;kle (which is the item's name) has two sides: a female one and a male one. End of story. The link given by the OP is in poor English.

Comment: @Lambie I think I've misread (or rather -not- read) many things. I didn't click on the link (Hey everybody when you write a question make sure it is self-contained with the links!) I am describing a normal seat belt buckle, not that plastic buckle in those pictures. I mean hey __the answers are right in the link already, right?__

Comment: The OP's thing is called a side release buckle. Don't shoot the messenger please.

Answer (score 3):

You could call them **plug** and **socket** if you want to avoid gender-based terms.

Merriam-Webster has

> [plug](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/plug)
> any of various devices resembling or functioning like a plug: such as
> a : a male fitting for making an electrical connection to a live circuit by insertion in a receptacle (such as an outlet)
> b : a device for connecting electric wires to a jack

and

> [socket](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/socket)
> : an opening or hollow that forms a holder for something

Comment: Is this an established usage for the device mentioned?

Comment: 'plug' and 'socket' are common with electrical devices, but I don't think I've ever heard them for mechanical parts. That is, "You could call them" those and you would be understood, but they aren't what is normally used.

Comment: The ends of things like computer USB and audio extension cables are almost always referred to as "male" and "female". I don't think non-Anglophones should be encouraged to think it's a good idea to avoid those terms.

Comment: **Socket**  is in common use as a general receptacle for something. Some people want to avoid the use of gender stereotypes, as has been successfully achieved by the gender neutral pronoun 'they'. Perhaps @FumbleFingers thinks that should not have happened. But in their example of electrical connections 'plug' and 'socket' are very well established.

Comment: Sockets are not all female, nor are the plugs for them all male. [This](https://cdn.futuregarden.co.uk/media/catalog/product/cache/009f738073fab68730337e83a3287f61/1/0/1000242000.jpg) is a female plug. It is designed to plug into a male socket.

Answer (score 3):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buckle), the names are **male buckle member** and **female buckle member**, so pretty close to what you called them:

> ***Side release buckle***
>
> A conventional **snap-fit buckle** that is formed by a **"male" buckle
> member—the hook end—and a "female" buckle member—the insertion end**.
> The **male buckle member** consists of a center rod and two spring
> prongs equally spaced from the center rod. The two spring arms each
> have a retaining block that terminates at the front end. The **female
> buckle member** has a front open side and two side holes which hold
> and secure the two spring arms of the **male buckle member**.[21] This
> sort of buckle may be found connecting many strapped items such as pet
> harnesses, safety harnesses, personal flotation jackets, fanny packs
> and other bags, belts, gun slings, and boots. It is **also known as
> the "parachute buckle"**. They are often used in conjunction with
> tri-glide slides.

[image: side release buckle, also known as parachute buckle and snap-fit buckle]

**UPDATE 8/26/22:**

If you are unsatisfied with the above, since what you describe is very much like what fastens a seatbelt, which has a male side that is called a "latch" and a female side that is called a "buckle" (i.e., the latch slides into the buckle until it latches), I'd imagine you could get away with using those terms instead.

Comment: "the insertion end" looks ambiguous to me

Comment: What @Henry said. Absent this full context, I'd probably understand "the insertion end" as meaning "the end with a part that gets inserted into something", rather than "the end into which something is inserted". And "the **hook** end" has no intuitive meaning for me in the context of side release buckles, even though I know perfectly well which side is which in a **hook and eye** fastener.

Comment: If I had my druthers, I'd call them the "tab end" and the "slot end," borrowing on the common instruction, "Insert Tab A into Slot B." But I don't have my druthers. It's not up to me. These are the terms, so if they look ambiguous to some folks, that's unfortunate, but it's also neither here nor there. The dictionary is chock-full of terms that on their face are ambiguous or even indecipherable, like how idioms are indecipherable on their face since their meaning is different than the literal meaning their words convey. As they say, that's the way the cookie crumbles.